# Automatically using facades in a package in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing some packages a lot of which are based on code that was in the main app, or from examples that are based on writing the code in an app rather than a package. I keep forgetting to add a `Use View;` or `Use Controller;` in the various files and am having to manually check and add these to every single PHP script (that needs them) in the package.

Is there a way of automating this so that I only have to declare them once in a package, or better still get them to pass through to the facades in the main app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't.

This is because your package code has its own namespace, and so does the Illuminate core.
PHP's use-statements are only on per-file basis.
When your scripts uses classes from another namespace, you have 2 options.

- Adding use-statements (to the Facades) to alias the class to the current namespace
- Referencing the full namespace of the facade (starting from the global namespace ), either the alias in the global namespace which Laravel automatically creates (\View), or the original full namespace of the facade (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\View)

Example of referencing the full namespace:

```
<?php

namespace My\Package;

class SomeClass
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // reference full namespace
        $view = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::make('someview');
        // or
        $view = \View::make
    }
}

?>
```

This might seem as a way to not have to use use-statements, but in my opinion it's worse. So I recommend u to just get used to adding these use-statements.

You should see it as a best practice: these use-statements clearly state the dependencies of your class (or file). It's always better to try and lower the amount of these.